# How to model a simple flight schedule in Combinatorial Optimisation

Tags: graph-theory, mathematical-modeling, network, network-flow

I have trouble with the following modeling exercise in Combinatorial Optimisation:

> You want to schedule $n$ flights with as few planes as possible. For each flight $i$ the travel time $t_i$ and the start time $d_i$ are given. Let further be $\delta(i,j)$ the time for all flights $i,j$ be the time required to prepare a plane for the flight $j$ after it is finished with flight $i$.
>
> Find a flight schedule that ensures all flights are done with as few planes as possible.

We are currently learnig about network flows in the lecture, so I suppose we should use this here.

My current attempt would be as follows. Start with a directed graph $G(V,E)$ with $\lvert V(G) \rvert = n$, where each edge $(i,j)$ connects two nodes $i$ and $j$ if the corresponding flights are viable to be performed after another, i.e. $d_i + \delta_{ij} + t_i \le d_j$. To use a network flow algorithm it would now be natural to define a capacity fucntion on this graph, but I do not see how this could help to solve the problem.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flight schedule corresponds to a [path cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_cover) in your directed (acyclic!) graph. Finding a schedule that uses the minimum number of planes then corresponds to the so-called minimum path cover problem. This can be solved by reduction to the maximum matching problem in bipartite graphs, as sketched [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Minimum_path_cover_in_directed_acyclic_graph). If you want, you can unpack this and write the maximum matching problem as a network flow problem.